# Does XP obtain increase with better combo of attacks in GOW 4?

Tags: god-of-war-2018

In God of War 4 PC, does the xp gained after a fight is constant, or it varies depending on the way it is fought, such as no-hit, combos, etc.,

Comment: What do you mean by "God of War 4"? Which version is it?

Comment: The remastered version for PC.